# How to awk all lines instead of only looking at the first

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script that allows you to enter your machine name, and then lets you know if the host is on the local network. Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter the host you would like to ping:"
read -r host

output=$(ruptime | awk '{print $1}')

if [ "$output" == "$host" ];
    then
        echo "$host is up"
    else
        echo "$host is down"
fi
```

This works when I enter my machine name 'ubuntu' since I am the only one on my LAN and the awk statement outputs 'ubuntu'.

If I run for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
    echo "Please enter the host you would like to ping:"
    read -r host

    output=$(cat /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}')

    if [ "$output" == "$host" ];
        then
            echo "$host is up"
        else
            echo "$host is down"
    fi
```

The output is 2 lines: localhost and ubuntu. If I then run the script and enter either one of those, it says it's not found.

I think the awk is only looking for the value in the first line. How can I have the script check every line from the output of the awk and then compare it to what was entered?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: awk *always* looks through all lines of its input. `output=$(cat /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}')` puts first column of *every line in your file* into a single string in `$output`. Of course, this string is not equal to any single hostname.

Comment: `$output` contains ALL the hostnames. You're comparing one name to all of them, they aren't equal.

Comment: BTW, `==` isn't guaranteed to work in `[` across shells; it's a better habit to use `=`, which is the only string comparison operator specified in the [standard for POSIX `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tips and advice! I didn't realize awk would print the first column of every line

Comment: awk programs consist of `CONDITION { ACTION }` pairs. If you leave out the condition, the default is to run the action for each line. If you leave out the action, the default is to print the entire line as-is. So you can put in a condition that tells awk to only do its action for *some* lines, but the default is all of them.

Comment: Thus, one could also address your requirements with `ruptime | awk -v host="$host" '$1 == host { found=1; print host " is up"; exit(1); } END { if(found == 0) { print host " is down"; } }'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `$output` to all the names. You're not checking if `$host` is one of them, you're checking if `$host` is equal to all of them at once.

`grep` is a better way to do this.

```
if ruptime | grep -q -w "$host"
then echo "$host is up"
else echo "$host is down"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your goal is to look at whether a given name is in the first column of the output from `ruptime`, that might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

hostname="target"
while read -r hostname _; do
  [[ $hostname = "$target" ]] && { echo "$target is up"; break; }
done < <(ruptime)
```

`read -r hostname _` puts only the first column of each line into `hostname`, putting remaining text into `_`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great but I find Barwar's answer to be much simpler for my needs. I appreciate the explanation and alternate way of completing the task.